# How many arrangements of $n$ $0$s and $m$ $1$s are there with $k$ runs of $0$s?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

How many arrangements are there of $n$ $0$s and $m$ $1$s with $k$ runs of $0$s? A run is a consecutive set ($1$ or more) of the same digit; eg.,$\underline{000}111\underline{0}1\underline{00}$  has three (underlined) runs of 0s.

Comment: With *at least* or with *exactly* $k$ runs of $0$?

Comment: exactly k runs of 0 question is available here http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.02/diana2.html

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Instead of looking at the $0$s and $1$s, look at the places where you change from one to the other.